# HDR 4K metadate delete in nvidia gpu trascoding

Tags: ffmpeg, gpu, ubuntu-20.04, hdr

I'm trying to code with my nvidia faster and I have achieved it directly with ffmpeg, since handbrake only uses the cpy even if I select gpu.

I have used this line of code and it works perfect for 4K variable bitrate, but I want it to have the HDR metadata for the movies that have it.

now the output removes two metadata

ffmpeg -i FILE_HDR.mkv  -c:v hevc_nvenc  -x265-params frameref=15:fast_pskip=0 -minrate 10000k -maxrate 20000k -b:v 20000k -bufsize 20350k -c:a copy  -sn /mnt/UHD/FILEHDR.mkv

what I try is to have a line of code with this

-4K HDR

- hevc_nvenc (to use the gpu)
- 2 audios without codifying that I copy them
- 16500 variable bitrate
- copy 2 subtitle files but without burning them on screen (for selection)

my system is UBUNTU 20.04
thanks

Answer (score 0):

my solution :

ffmpeg  -i /FILE.mkv -c:v:0 nvenc_hevc -preset llhq -profile:v:0 main10 -vb 15000k -c:a:0 mp2 -b:a:0 384k -f mpegts -metadata:s:v:0 master-display="G(13248,34499)B(7500,2999)R(34000,15999)WP(15700,17550)L(10000000,100)" -color_range 1 -color_trc smpte2084 -color_primaries bt2020 -colorspace 9 -y /file_out.mkv

or copy audio

ffmpeg  -i /mnt/Z1tera/conversion/file.mkv -c:v:0 nvenc_hevc -preset llhq -profile:v:0 main10 -vb 15000k  -metadata:s:v:0 master-display="G(13248,34499)B(7500,2999)R(34000,15999)WP(15700,17550)L(10000000,100)" -color_range 1 -color_trc smpte2084 -color_primaries bt2020 -colorspace 9 -y  -c:a copy -sn /mnt/UHD/file.mkv

Comment: There's a way to do so via ffmpeg's libplacebo filter. Share your HDR sample(s) here and I'll be back with command lines to test.